# Query in function is not executing

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to create a button where you can delete a record selected using trv.bind. I can select fine as I already tried using print to display the OID when selecting but when I add a delete function, it does nothing and gives me no errors. From my understanding I am selecting the specific row through the OID but my function does not delete. The query is not executing.

I made a sample code that mirrors mine.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, LabelFrame, StringVar
import tkinter.messagebox
import sqlite3

#cursor
conn = sqlite3.connect('newtest.db')

#cursor is needed for sql functions
c = conn.cursor()

top = tkinter.Tk()

q = StringVar()
t1 = StringVar()
t2 = StringVar()

#this grabs each ID
def getrows(event):
    rowid = trv.identify_row(event.y)
    item = trv.item(trv.focus())
    t1.set(item['values'][0])
    t2.set(item['values'][1])

def pdelete():
    oid = t1.get()
    query = "DELETE FROM products WHERE oid = "+oid
    c.execute(query)

    conn.commit()

def update(show):
    trv.delete(*trv.get_children())
    for i in show:
        trv.insert("", 'end', values=i)

    return show


conn.commit()

def query_database():
    query = "SELECT oid, pdesc from products"
    conn = sqlite3.connect('newtest.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(query)
    show = c.fetchall()

    return show

box4 = LabelFrame(top, text="Products Summary")
box4.pack (fill="both", expand="yes", padx=20, pady=10)

trv = ttk.Treeview(box4, column=(1,2), show="headings", height="20")
style=ttk.Style(trv)
style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=20)

trv.pack(side=LEFT)
trv.heading(1, text="Product ID")
trv.heading(2, text="Product Description")


conn = sqlite3.connect('newtest.db')
query = "SELECT oid, pdesc from products"
c.execute(query)
show = c.fetchall()
update(show)

#deletebutton
btn6 = ttk.Button(box4, text='Delete', command=pdelete)
btn6.pack(side=RIGHT)

#select
trv.bind('<Double 1>', getrows)

top.title("deletetest")
top.geometry("1500x1200")
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Sqlite3 delete function with button". Can you narrow it down to either the button in python not working or sqlite not deleting?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear enough. SQlite3 is not deleting. I tried printing the OID through the button. So I think the C.execute(query) is not running

Comment: Try `query = "DELETE FROM products WHERE oid = ?",(oid,)` and execute it and how are you verifying if the data is deleted or not?

Comment: So do you think that "SQlite3 is not deleting." because "the C.execute(query) is not running"? In that case we can stop bothering about sqlite and you could focus your question and your [mre] on the deleting query not being executed. Please narrow it down.

Comment: @CoolCloud Sorry for not clarifying. I am verifying both through the looking at the date in the database if it has changed or not and I have a function which updates the data displayed in my GUI. I tried your recommendation and it still does not affect the database. I apologize if it doesn't make sense, I am not proficient at any of this.

Comment: Are you sure the `oid` your trying to delete exists? try `print(t1.get())` and verify it is what you want